# How to use subprocesses.call and pipe one output to a txt file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, pipe

Other scripts are involved so I don't know how to ask this with all of the tino.

Right now I have this command,

```
 subprocess.call(['python2.7', 'cello_client.py', 'get_results',
                  '--jobid','pythonTest4', '--filename',
                  'pythonTest4_dnacompiler_output.txt','>','out.txt'])
```

It's suppoosed to push the output to a text file out.txt, but it doesn't do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `>` is a shell redirection command but you didn't run through a shell. You can do what the shell would do: open the file and attach it as the program's `stdout`.

```
subprocess.call(['python2.7', 'cello_client.py', 'get_results',
    '--jobid','pythonTest4', '--filename',
    'pythonTest4_dnacompiler_output.txt'],
    stdout=open('out.txt', 'wb'))
```

You can read `stdout` directly into memory with a different subprocess command:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['python2.7', 'cello_client.py', 'get_results',
    '--jobid','pythonTest4', '--filename',
    'pythonTest4_dnacompiler_output.txt'])
out_text, err_text = proc.communicate()
return_code = proc.returncode
```

Comment: This works great, thanks so much! I have a followup question. as soon as I write to this text file, I open it and read it in, then close the file.  Is there a way to edit the above command to simply save the output as a string in my program?

Comment: Updated to show `Popen.communicate`